# Connecting to couchbase running on alternate ports using java client

Tags: java, couchbase, database, nosql

I'm using couchbase-client 2.3.2 for Java and Couchbase server Community 4.0

So I'm experimenting with running Couchbase on non-standard ports using the documentation at [Couchbase website](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-ports.html)

I've managed to start Couchbase using these alternate ports but I've only managed to change some of the ports in the java client, here's my code:

```
        final CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .bootstrapCarrierDirectPort(21210)
            .bootstrapHttpDirectPort(9091)
            .build();
    return CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "10.0.2.15");
```

My program is able to connect to couchbase and so some things, however I still need to change the view port (default 8092) and the query port (default 8093) in the client. as a result I'm met with these errors:

> 2016-09-30 14:03:49.696 [] WARN  c.c.c.c.e.Endpoint - [null][QueryEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS:  ! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /10.0.2.15:8093
>
> 2016-09-30 14:03:52.077 [] WARN  c.c.c.c.e.Endpoint - [null][ViewEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 2048 MILLISECONDS:  ! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /10.0.2.15:8092

So the client still tries to connect to 8092 and 8093 when in fact I've changed those to 9092 and 9093

Comment: I fixed port 8093 by adding {query_port, 9093}. to static_config, still can't figure out how to fix port 8092....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's completely undocumented, you need to add those ports to static_config as well:

```
{capi_port, 9092}.
{query_port, 9093}.
```

and then it works, hope someone at couchbase sees this and updates their documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc on 2.3.4 (http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.3.4/), I believe what you want is this:

DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.Builder viewEndpoints(int viewServiceEndpoints)